# Unable to plot the data calculated from elements of each row from a data file

Tags: python

I have a data file which contains 4 elements per row as `keV`, `keVerror`, `Counts` and `Countserror` and each element is separated by a space. For each row, I want to calculate the Hertz(Hz) and Flux density(`Fnu`) using these 4 elements and plot them. So, after reading the four elements of any row, I want to calculate the Hz from keV(simple multiplication) and then use this Hz value to calculate the Fnu by multiplying with the counts value for the same row. I would also like to write the output in a file. My code is able to calculate the Hz as the written output txt file matches my manually calculated values but the produced plot is showing different values.

First few lines of the file :

```
   keV        keV error    counts       Counts error
0.616850019 7.29998946E-3 6.82969764E-2 5.15005877E-3
0.631449997 7.30001926E-3 7.20156059E-2 5.33540128E-3
0.646049976 7.29998946E-3 8.04692879E-2 5.47288591E-3
0.65882504 5.47501445E-3 0.102332868 7.17073539E-3
```

my inexperienced attempt at code writing goes like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

(kev,keverr,cts,ctserr)=np.loadtxt("sedtotal.dat", usecols=(0,1,2,3),unpack=True)

hz=kev*2.415e17
hzerr=keverr*2.415e17

fnu=kev*cts*1.602e-9
fnuerr=kev*ctserr*1.602e-9

nufnu=hz*fnu
nufnuerr=hz*fnuerr

plt.figure(1)
plt.ylabel(r'log $\nu$F$\nu$ (Jy-Hz)',fontsize = 12)
plt.xlabel(r'log $\nu$ (Hz)',fontsize =12)

print(hz,fnu) 
plt.errorbar(hz,hzerr,fnu,fnuerr, fmt='ro', color="red", elinewidth=None, capsize=3,barsabove=True)

plt.yscale('log')
plt.xscale('log')

f = open('sedtotal.txt', 'w')
print >> f, 'Filename:', hz, fnu, fnuerr  # to write the output in a file
f.close()

ax = plt.gca()
plt.show()
```

Comment: You should really elaborate on your issue a bit in the question. Beyond the general title, I'm not sure what you expect your code to do exactly and what it does instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!